# Fast integration of 2D distribution across lines parallel to y-axis

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

I'm struggling with a small data set and a slow calculation. I have *hundreds* of small 2D data arrays and need to integrate across several lines parallel to the y-axis.

Let me start with the data array:

```
data={{51.6,10},{16.52,18},{48.835,12},{72.975,7},{61.085,19},{78.362,11},{24.312,25},
      {26.818,5},{37.336,5},{70.647,18},{48.783,35},{40.379,35},{75.926,8},{23.226,8},
      {54.727,18},{116.046,12},{20.597,20},{21.973,28},{74.821,7},{56.408,51}};
```

After rescaling and truncating the distribution, it looks like this:

```
dnorm=Transpose[Rescale/@Transpose[data]];
pdf[x_,y_]=PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{{0,∞},{0,∞}},
               SmoothKernelDistribution[dnorm,Automatic,{"Radial","Gaussian"}]],{x,y}];
ContourPlot[pdf[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

[image: plot of distribution]

I am interested in the profile across a line parallel to the y-axis (say e.g. $x=0.5$) and do handle this profile as a distribution for this specific x-value. I need the 95% quantile for this specific distribution at the specific x-value.

Finally, I am interested in all the quantile-values for all x-values between 0 and 1 (in the rescaled domain) and do rescale them back afterwards.

I have written the following function, which works but need approx. 10 seconds (even without the line plot and sampling at 20 data points between 0 and 1). I have to evaluate *hundreds* of data sets with this function, so I **need to speed it up**.

```
myquantile[d_List,q_]:=Block[{dnorm,pdf,x,y,func,int,ξ,ψ,sol,invx,invy,lp},
  dnorm=Transpose[Rescale/@Transpose[d]];
  pdf[x_,y_]=PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{{0,∞},{0,∞}},
                 SmoothKernelDistribution[dnorm,Automatic,{"Radial","Gaussian"}]],{x,y}];
  func[ξ_]:=Block[{},
    int=NIntegrate[pdf[ξ,y],{y,0,1}];
    ψ/.FindRoot[NIntegrate[pdf[ξ,y],{y,0,ψ}]/int==q,{ψ,0.8,0.9},Evaluated->False]];
    {invx[x_],invy[x_]}=Rescale[x,{0,1},#]&/@({Min[#],Max[#]}&/@Transpose[d]);
    sol=Interpolation[Table[{invx[x],invy[func[x]]},{x,0,1,0.05}]
  ];
  lp=Plot[sol[x],{x,invx[0],invx[1]},AxesOrigin->{invx[0],invy[0]}];
  {sol,lp}
];
myquantile[data, 0.95] // Timing
```

The final `InterpolatingFunction` looks like this (in the regular domain):

[image: plot of interpolant]

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Is it possible to get the line distribution in a different and faster way? A `MarginalDistribution` is pretty much what I want, but it is the distribution for all x-values and it gives me no information on individual x-values.

Thanks!

Comment: @0x4A4D: how have you changed the \[Psi] etc. into the "real" symbols? It was showing up differently, when I posted this question?

Comment: Well, magic... okay, no. I knew the Unicode for these, so I put 'em in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a partial differential equation to integrate along $y$. It costs less than 0.1 second on my old machine.

```
sol = NDSolve[{
               D[cdf[x, y], y] == pdf[x, y],
               cdf[x, 0] == 0
              },
              cdf, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

quantileLine = ContourPlot[Evaluate[
                      cdf[x, y]/cdf[x, 1] == .9 /. sol[[1]]],
                      {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or if you want an explicit `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
quantileLineFunc = Interpolation@
    Cases[quantileLine,
        GraphicsComplex[pts_, others__] :>
            Part[pts,
             Cases[others, Line[idx_] :> idx, ∞][[1]]
             ]
        ][[1]]
```

Comment: @ Silvia: thanks a lot; your answer is very obvious, since you just use the dependency between the cdf and pdf. I was completely blocked in mind and haven't thought about other directions to solve this. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @akm You're welcome!